# preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given error in CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, email, cakephp

I am trying to send an email with CakeEmail and it is failing on `$email->to()` method. The error messages can be seen on this image: http://i47.tinypic.com/240yq86.png

Basically, I am getting this two errors:

```
Warning (2): preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given [CORE/Cake/Utility/Validation.php, line 815]
Warning (4096): Object of class CakeEmail could not be converted to string [CORE/Cake/basics.php, line 566]
```

This is my `sendEmail()` method:

```
function sendEmail($id, $email, $token)
{      
    print_r($email);
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->from('admin@gmail.com');
    $email->to($email);
    $email->subject('Activate your account');     
    $activate_url = 'http://' . env('SERVER_NAME') .'/users/activate/'.$id.'/'.$token;
    $message = "Thank you for signing up. Click on the activation link to activate your account \n";
    return $email->send($message.$activate_url);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some basic php error:

change function param 2 name to `$to`;
change `print_r($email)` to `print_r($to)`;
   change the $email->to($email);`to`$email->to($to);`

Comment: Thanks for trying but that really isn't the problem =)

Comment: That's the problem. You didnt noticed that reciver email is replaced by your instance of cakeEmail. So you are getting the error

Comment: Sigh. It's 5am. I really should stop this. You're right. I'm getting over myself.

Comment: @JohnathanAu Yes, it is the problem ;-) You've passed in `$email`, then overwritten it with your Cake object.  This sort of thing  is why I asked you to do a var_dump immediately prior to the `to()` call.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tested it and it works. Bed time! Sorry again =P

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  Completely missed the obvious problem that others have picked up...

So, I was looking for *other* issues that might have upset the class's configuration...

As per http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html, `from()` accepts an array (although it's not explicitly stated that you *have* to use an array).

Try this line instead:

`$email->from(array('admin@gmail.com' => 'Admin at gMail'));`

Comment: The error is at the to() method. Nevertheless, I've tried your suggestion and I still get the error.

Comment: @JohnathanAu so what are you passing to `to()`?? ie do a `var_dump ($email);` just prior to the `to()` call. My guess, based on the error message is that it's not a string ;-)

Comment: I am passing in email addresses. I am printing them out as you can see on the first line on the sendEmail method.

Comment: @JohnathanAu :-) I reiterate what I said 10 mins ago... do a `var_dump ($email);` _just prior to_ the `to()` call. My guess, based on the error message is that it's not a string ;-)

Comment: @JohnathanAu There's nothing like a fresh set of eyes.  I must admit I missed the bleeding obvious problem too... which I do a lot!  Which is why I suggested adding some code to _confirm/deny_ our assumptions rather than relying on them!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `$email` in param is been overwritten by `$email = new CakeEmail()` change that to a different variable `$to`

```
function sendEmail($id, $to, $token)
{      
    print_r($email);
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->from('admin@gmail.com');
    $email->to($to);
    $email->subject('Activate your account');     
    $activate_url = 'http://' . env('SERVER_NAME') .'/users/activate/'.$id.'/'.$token;
    $message = "Thank you for signing up. Click on the activation link to activate your account \n";
    return $email->send($message.$activate_url);
}
```